# Cypress can't load fonts from absolute url while open through its dashboard

Tags: reactjs, fonts, cypress, e2e-testing

I've a simple web server for e2e purposes, built with *create react app* and *react app rewired*.
Cypress runs perfectly against this web server, the only issue I am facing is about the fonts.
They are included with an external url.

Since I launch the web server regularly, the react application is able to be fed with the url for the proper fonts.

Once Cypress open the browser with the command `cypress open` the console log shows this error and fonts indeed are not loaded.

```
GET https://[URL.EXTENSION]/[FONT.WOFF2] net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

**BEGIN EDIT**

I noticed that the issue occurs on my company VPN and not on my regular network configuration, so as I already said, the fonts are not loaded just in the browser of Cypress, if I

- view the website from a regular browser
- access those fonts url copying them in the browser

any issue is occurring

**END EDIT**

Where is lying the error? Do I miss something in the configuration?
Thanks